# await not blocking until Task finishes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to block `RequestHandler.ParseAll()` with `await ConsumerTask;`, but when i set a breakpoint there, i ALWAYS get the "Done..." output first... and then `Parse2()` fails with a NullReferenceException. (thats my guess: "the GC starts cleaning up because `_handler` got out of scope")

Anyway, I can't figure out why that happens.

```
class MainClass
{
    public async void DoWork()
    {
        RequestHandler _handler = new RequestHandler();
        string[] mUrls;
        /* fill mUrls here with values */
        await Task.Run(() => _handler.ParseSpecific(mUrls));
        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
    }
}
static class Parser
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> QueryWebPage(string url) { /*Query the url*/ }

    public static async Task Parse1(Query query) 
    { 
        Parallel.ForEach(/*Process data here*/);
    }

    public static async Task Parse2(Query query)
    {
        foreach(string line in query.WebPage)
            /* Here i get a NullReference exception because query.WebPage == null */
    }
}
sealed class RequestHandler
{
    private BlockingCollection<Query> Queue;
    private Task ConsumerTask = Task.Run(() => /* call consume() for each elem in the queue*/);

    private async void Consume(Query obj)
    {
        await (obj.BoolField ? Parser.Parse1(obj) : Parser.Parse2(obj));
    }

    public async void ParseSpecific(string[] urls)
    {
        foreach(string v in urls)
            Queue.Add(new Query(await QueryWebPage(v), BoolField: false));

        Queue.CompleteAdding();
        await ConsumerTask;
        await ParseAll(true);
    }

    private async Task ParseAll(bool onlySome)
    {
        ReInit();
        Parallel.ForEach(mCollection, v => Queue.Add(new Query(url, BoolField:false)));
        Queue.CompleteAdding();
        await ConsumerTask;
        /* Process stuff further */
    }
}
struct Query
{
    public readonly string[] WebPage;
    public readonly bool BoolField;
    public Query(uint e, IEnumerable<string> page, bool b) : this()
    {
        Webpage = page.ToArray();
        BoolField = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is pretty complicated (more so for having lots of async methods which don't have an `Async` suffix) - are you able to cut it down at all?

Comment: `ParseSpecific` returns on its first `await` statement. You don't `await ParseSpecific`

Comment: @JonSkeet: I cut it down as far as possible, without trying to leave anything important away... but i will try.

Comment: @Nefarion: CodesInChaos has figured it out in his comment - and I'm elaborating.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I hope you don't mind me basically jumping on the fact that you spotted what was wrong :) Well caught, sir!

Comment: Remember, `await` does not mean "block until this task is completed". It means the exact opposite of that; it means "return immediately so that your caller can keep on doing more work; when that work is done and the task is completed, resume after the await".

Comment: @JonSkeet It's fine. I usually comment like this when I'm too lazy to write a full answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CodesInChaos has spotted the problem in comments. It stems from having async methods returning `void`, which you should almost *never* do - it means you've got no way to track them.

Instead, if your async methods don't have any actual value to return, you should just make them return `Task`.

What's happening is that `ParseSpecific` is only running synchronously until the first `await QueryWebPage(v)` that doesn't complete immediately. It's then returning... so the task started here:

```
await Task.Run(() => _handler.ParseSpecific(mUrls));
```

... completes immediately, and "Done" gets printed.

Once you've made all your async methods return `Task`, you can await them. You also won't need `Task.Run` at all. So you'd have:

```
public async void DoWork()
{
    RequestHandler _handler = new RequestHandler();
    string[] mUrls;
    await _handler.ParseSpecific(mUrls);
    Console.WriteLine("Done...");
}
```

...

```
public async TaskParseSpecific(string[] urls)
{
    foreach(string v in urls)
    {
        // Refactored for readability, although I'm not sure it really
        // makes sense now that it's clearer! Are you sure this is what
        // you want?
        var page = await QueryWebPage(v);
        Queue.Add(new Query(page, false);
    }

    Queue.CompleteAdding();
    await ConsumerTask;
    await ParseAll(true);
}
```

Your `Reinit` method also needs changing, as currently the `ConsumerTask` will basically complete almost immediately, as `Consume` will return immediately as it's *another* async method returning void.

To be honest, what you've got looks *very* complex, without a proper understanding of async/await. I would read up more on async/await and then probably start from scratch. I strongly suspect you can make this much, much simpler. You might also want to read up on [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh228603.aspx) which is designed to make producer/consumer scenarios simpler.

Comment: @Nefarion Just returning `Task` doesn't help. You still need to await it. And you only need `TaskEx.Run` if you want it to run on a separate thread(you probably don't).

Comment: Thank you two for the huge help, i did not know about the "async void" methods not beeing awaitable :)
I fixed that all, and now i get a funny little error here:  `Parallel.ForEach(mCollection, v => Queue.Add(new Query(url, BoolField:false)));`
about the BlockingCollection not beeing open for writing, so i assume it continued without waiting for the parallel loop to complete...
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Nefarion: Well as I said, there's a lot more to fix in your code - but rather than just try to fix it, I'd take a step back, learn more about async/await, and also look at Dataflow. Then take another look at your problem with a fresh perspective.

Comment: Thanks all for your help!
@JonSkeet: My programm is made up from a few dll's and many other classes, i simplified and reduced the example as far as possible, and left out methods where i could, so i could give an overview. The real programm looks a lot different, but the example explained the situation i had very well, so i chose it. I just replaced the `Parallel.ForEach` with a simple `foreach` loop, that works fine, and i will have a look at the problem tonight. Thank you for the great tip with the `async void`'s :)